# kcheckpass error opening /var/log/faillog

Tags: pam, setuid

I am seeing the following errors:

```
$ journalctl -b -p3
-- Logs begin at Mon 2016-05-16 21:40:56 EDT, end at Wed 2016-07-27 22:30:13 EDT. --
Jul 27 22:22:26 x99 kcheckpass[5682]: pam_tally(kde:auth): Error opening /var/log/faillog for update
Jul 27 22:22:26 x99 kcheckpass[5682]: pam_tally(kde:auth): Error opening /var/log/faillog for read
Jul 27 22:22:26 x99 kcheckpass[5682]: pam_tally(kde:auth): Error opening /var/log/faillog for update
Jul 27 22:22:26 x99 kcheckpass[5682]: pam_tally(kde:auth): Error opening /var/log/faillog for read
Jul 27 22:22:26 x99 kcheckpass[5682]: pam_tally(kde:setcred): Error opening /var/log/faillog for update
Jul 27 22:22:26 x99 kcheckpass[5682]: pam_tally(kde:setcred): Error opening /var/log/faillog for update
```

The man page for kcheckpass says:

> kcheckpass - KDE's authentication program
>
> Any program, such as a screensaver with a lock option, that needs to authenticate a user, can use kcheckpass. kcheckpass is a simple
>   setuid program that returns 0 if the user has been authenticated, and
>   1 if not. Other programs that need user authentication can use
>   kcheckpass witout having setuid status, thus simplifying programs and
>   enhancing system security.
>
> ```
> SECURITY
> kcheckpass must be setuid on systems that use shadow passwords.
> ```

I understand that the setuid permission bit tells Linux to run a program with the effective user id of the owner instead of the executor.

However, I do not understand how to implement the solution in this case. What exactly do I need to do?

Here are the existing permissions on /var/log/faillog

```
$ ls -la /var/log/faillog 
-rw------- 1 root root 32096 Aug  9 12:56 /var/log/faillog
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [Arch Linux forum](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=1643987#p1643987), there is a better answer:

Edit this file and make the 2 changes stated below (remove a line and insert a new line):

```
sudo nano /etc/pam.d/system-login
```

Remove this entire line:

```
auth       required   pam_tally.so         onerr=succeed file=/var/log/faillog
```

Insert in its place this line:

```
auth       required   pam_tally2.so
```

Create the log file:

```
touch /var/log/tallylog
chmod 600 /var/log/tallylog
```

See more details at the [Arch Forum](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=1643987#p1643987) for an explanation of why this may be the better solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can run this command:

```
sudo chmod +s /usr/lib/kcheckpass
```

Depending on the distro you are using it could be located in another directory, so it could be `/usr/libexec/kcheckpass`.

Comment: Could you elaborate on what this does and how it fixes the problem? I understand your command will make the kcheckpass program run as the file's owner instead of the user who invoked it. This solution depends on some knowledge of what the owner of kcheckpass and /var/log/faillog which is not stated. Why is this a better solution than changing the ownership or permissions of /var/log/faillog? I would think it isn't.

Comment: As the original question stated, kcheckpass was meant to be run with SUID so it had the proper permissions to perform its tasks. This may have changed since the kcheckpass rewrite (more information here https://blog.martin-graesslin.com/blog/2017/05/a-sandbox-for-the-screen-locker/).So unless you're seeing this issue I wouldn't bother to change it to SUID unless you are seeing any issues. When I was seeing this error in my log I was also having login issues as well, so the messages were indicative of a larger issue.